# Checking against if statement giving wrong result?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the code

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$referral = $_POST['refer'];
$referred = false;
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Cannot connect to database");
$query = mysql_query("Select * from member"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
  $table_users = $row['username'];
  $table_email = $row['email'];
  $table_phone = $row['phone'];
  if($referral == $table_users)
  {
    $referred = true;
  }
  if($username == $table_users || $email == $table_email || $phone == $table_phone)
  {
    $bool = false;
  }
}
if(($bool))
{
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);   
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (username, password, email, phone, refer) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$phone', '$referral')"); 
  if($referred)
  {
    $from="Sent from test";
    $subject="New user referred.";
    $message="A new user " . $username . " has been referred by " . $referral . "Please stay updated. ";
    mail("mymail", $subject, $message, $from);
  }
  $_SESSION['login'] = true;
  echo "Thank you for registering with us.You can <a href=\"index.php\">login</a> now to start earning.";
}
```

If the referral code field is left empty or it does not match any value in database it still sends 
the mail. So, what is going on here? I have added some more code. I left a part of it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This statement `if($referral == $table_users)` doesn't look right. You have not set the `$referral` variable anywhere in your code.

Comment: To add on to this, you should change the `if` statement to `if (isset($referral) && $referral == $table_users) { ... }`.

Comment: @ﱞﱞﱞﱞﱞﱞ You should still use the `isset` technique anyway. It's good practice because it reduces warnings from a non-set `$_POST[]`.

Comment: You have to do some more debugging. How many rows are returned by the query and what are the values? Do a `var_dump($bool);` just before the `if(($bool))` statement to confirm that the value is true (such it will be). Either the $username, $email or $phone match up with the rows in your database.